# how to open selenium ide at run time via eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium

Can anyone tell me the eclipse code for launching selenium ide automatically at run time in firefox.
(while running, new instance of browser is created so no selenium ide or  plugins are present there).

Here is the code which i am using but its not working. Please help me out.

FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile=null;
        try {

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\workspace\\Seleniumdb\\selenium-ide-2.9.0.xpi");
        firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
        firefoxProfile.addExtension(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, firefoxProfile);
    WebDriver driver = null;
    try {
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, install your required plugins in firefox.

Then, launch `firefox.exe` with `-p` key.

Create profile.

Use this profile to instantiate you WebDriver instance.

When launched, all your plugins with their settings will be there.